# Dictionary inside class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create dictionaries / objects inside my javascript class and run it through nodejs but I'm getting this error:

> params.js:4
>   costPerHr = {
>
> ```
>           ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

My object looks like this:

```
module.exports = class Params {
  constructor() {}

  costPerHr = {
    internal: 100,
    shore: 50,
  };

  hoursPerMonth = 160;

  swhwMultiplier = {
    2: 280 / hoursPerMonth,
    5: 470 / hoursPerMonth,
  };
};
```

Comment: What version of Node.js are you using? Class fields are very new in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For setting properties in classes, you have to set them in the constructor:

```js
module.exports = class Params {
    constructor() {
        this.costPerHr = {
            internal: 100,
            shore: 50,
        };

        this.hoursPerMonth = 160;

        this.swhwMultiplier = {
            2: 280 / this.hoursPerMonth,
            5: 470 / this.hoursPerMonth,
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the syntax you're using is yet available in JavaScript.

There is a Stage 3 ECMAScript proposal - "Class Fields" by Daniel Ehrenberg and Jeff Morrison to add this feature.

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields

In the meantime, you'll have to resort to adding setters/getters, or setting the fields in the constructor (as @Oliver has pointed out!)

An example using class getters:

```
module.exports = class Params {
    constructor() {}

    get costPerHr() {
        return {
            internal: 100,
            shore: 50,
        }
    }

    get hoursPerMonth() { 
        return 160; 
    }

    get swhwMultiplier() { return {
        2: 280 / hoursPerMonth,
        5: 470 / hoursPerMonth,
    };}

    // Add a static getter
    static get my_static() { 
        return 160; 
    }
};
```

And then access like:

```
console.log("Cost per hour: ", params.costPerHr);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, do the class have to be initialized for getters and setters to work?

Comment: The class does need to be initialized!

Comment: Damm was hoping it didn't :/ It would have been a neat way to have a class returning static values

Comment: My bad.. you can create static getters! e.g. static get my_static { return 42;}.

Comment: That's pretty interesting. May have to try them out in the future.